# Update with prepared statement executing improperly

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pycharm

So I'm working in a Python 3.5.2 venv with SQLAlchemy and MySQL. I'm trying to update the status of an order (row) in a table. This requires simply changing the value of one column in a row. The following shows the function I'm working with:

```
def update_order_status(self, order):
    newstatus = self.orderwindow.status.currentIndex()
    orderid = order.orderid

    stmt = update(Order)\
        .where(Order.orderid == orderid).values(status=newstatus)

    session.execute(stmt)   
    session.commit()
```

`newstatus` is an integer value taken from the current choice set 
in a dropdown menu presented to the user. Upon the `session.commit()`the following errors are

```
   .....

  File "C:\Python35\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 292, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'Patient' for column 'bill' at row 1") [SQL: 'UPDATE `order` SET bill=%s, ship=%s, status=%s, flavor=%s WHERE `order`.orderid = %s'] [parameters: ('Patient', 'Pickup', 'Received', 7, 100000)]

......
Process finished with exit code 1
```

The parameters executed are not at all what is shown in the prepared statement. It should only be updating the row with the orderid matching the one provided as a parameter to the function and the status from the dropdown.

I've updated all packages and tried other methods of updating including `setattr(order, "status", newstatus)`

I'm unsure of what to do to diagnose this error.

EDIT: I forgot to mention earlier that this function actually works flawlessly in a python console after copy-pasting my database declarations script first.

Comment: Have you tried running that code separately in it's own [mcve]?  My guess is you have a global variable with the same name as one in your function.

Comment: @JeffUK Ironically, this function works flawlessly in PyCharm's python console.

Comment: That's not ironic! It supports my theory, did you check for globals with the same names? Try renaming all the variables within your function just in case

Comment: To add to what @JeffUK has requested, please include *full* tracebacks when asking for debugging help.

Comment: I've pasted the full traceback [here](https://pastebin.com/x3qdbHMs). I've also tried renaming the variables to avoid conflict and got the same result

Answer (score 0):

Seems I've answered my own question. I remembered that I was querying the order table earlier in my program and then changing its attributes from integers to user-friendly strings. When the `update` was being called, it was using the now changed order object which had values contradicting the table column types.

I didn't know that the `update` function attempts to update the entire object rather than just the columns provided in the `.values()` field. As a result I've had to revamp my handling of orders and instead I'm putting them into dictionaries and referencing the table again to update the original order.

Comment: It doesn't update the whole object, just the values you pass it, but from your description it sounds like you've done something like `order.bill = 'Patient'` before. ORM object's attributes are instrumented and those assignments produce change history that is [flushed to the DB before new statements are executed, if autoflush is in use](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#flushing).

Comment: @IljaEverilä that must be what has happened. The `setattr` I was performing on the objects was being flushed with the commit.